# How to get count of items which are created today in yii2?

Tags: yii2

Sample data in  my collection : 
created_at  :  2018-04-29 05:25:28.000Z

I'm using `TimestampBehavior`,

```
'timestamp' => [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'attributes' => [
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'created_at',
                ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_at',
            ],
            'value' => function() { $now = new \DateTime('NOW'); return new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))*1000); },
        ],
```

This is my count function :

```
 public function count_users () {
       $cnt = Users::find ()->select (['_id', 'created_at'])->where (['created_at'=>date ('Y-m-d')])->all ();
       return count ($cnt);
 }
```

How to use find select with a date?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the count() function

You could use the count() function  and new Expression('NOW()')

```
public function count_users () {
       $cnt = Users::find ()->select (['_id', 'created_at'])
        ->where (['created_at' => new \yii\db\Expression('curdate()')]->count();
       retur $cnt;
 }
```

[**`yii-db-query`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query)

[**`yii-db-query#count()-detail`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#count()-detail)

Comment: You dont need to `count($cnt)`, `->count()` returns the actual count your solution will return `1` in case the result is between `1-9` and `2` if result between `10-99`

Comment: and `NOW()` return `datetime` not `date` it will bring records created at exact `datetime` but not for the current day.

Answer (score 1):

Change your where condition like below and try

```
public function count_users () {
       $cnt = Users::find ()->where('DATE(created_at)=CURDATE()')->count();
       return $cnt;
}
```

[**`yii-db-query#count()-detail`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#count()-detail)

Comment: why not just `return Users::find ()->where('DATE(created_at)=CURDATE()')->count();` and make it one liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce it to one-liner by using `count()` as per suggestions above or using  [**`scalar()`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#scalar()-detail)

> scalar(): returns the value of the first column in the first row of
>   the query result.

```
public function count_users(){
    return Users::find()
           ->select([new \yii\db\Expression('COUNT(id) as total')])
           ->where(['DATE(created_at)'=>new \yii\db\Expression('CURDATE()')])
           ->scalar();
}
```

Comment: My collection looks like  : created_at : 2018-05-01 05:25:28.000Z : Date.  Will it work? I'm getting 0 only.

Comment: @BeginnerDev how are you saving the date in the table are you using `TimeStampBehavior` ?

Comment: why are you using `MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime to save the date? @BeginnerDev

Comment: It's already there. I have to count it now.  Is there any other solutions please?