# Yii 2 how to get all data within current day

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

Basically ProductOffer table.
Migration

```
$this->createTable('product_offer', [
    'id'            => $this->primaryKey(),
    'product_id'    => $this->bigInteger(20) . ' NOT NULL',
    'customer_id'   => $this->bigInteger(20),
    'coupon_code'   => $this->string(),
    'offer'         => $this->string(),
    'customer_name' => $this->string(),
    'email_address' => $this->string(),
    'phone_number'  => $this->string(),
    'note'          => $this->text(),
    'admin_note'    => $this->text(),
    'status'        => $this->tinyInteger(),
    'created'       => $this->dateTime() . ' NOT NULL',
    'modified'      => $this->dateTime(),
]);
```

Now I have data in this table and created query.

```
$stamp = mktime(0, 0, 0);
$testQuery = self::find()->where([
    'and',
    ['=', 'status', self::STATUS_REJECTED],
    ['=', 'product_id', $this->product_id],
    ['=', 'email_address', $this->email_address],
    ['>', 'created', date('m-d-Y H:i:s',$stamp)]
]);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($testQuery->all());
echo "</pre>";
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => app\models\ProductOffer Object
    (
        [verifyCode] => 
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => Test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] =>  Rejected 
                [created] => 2018-05-16 04:38:28
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 48
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => Test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] => 0
                [created] => 2018-05-16 04:38:28
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

    [1] => app\models\ProductOffer Object
    (
        [verifyCode] => 
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 50
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => Test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] =>  Rejected 
                [created] => 2018-05-17 04:39:55
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 50
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => Test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] => 0
                [created] => 2018-05-17 04:39:55
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

    [2] => app\models\ProductOffer Object
    (
        [verifyCode] => 
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 51
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] =>  Rejected 
                [created] => 2018-05-17 04:43:29
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 51
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] => 0
                [created] => 2018-05-17 04:43:29
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

    [3] => app\models\ProductOffer Object
    (
        [verifyCode] => 
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 55
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => Test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] =>  Rejected 
                [created] => 2018-05-17 04:51:57
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 55
                [product_id] => 111
                [customer_id] => 
                [coupon_code] => 
                [offer] => 23
                [customer_name] => Aljay Mallari
                [email_address] => asrockg07@gmail.com
                [phone_number] => 958568574
                [note] => Test
                [admin_note] => 
                [status] => 0
                [created] => 2018-05-17 04:51:57
                [modified] => 
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )
);
```

Today in our time zone is 5/17/2018, I want to get data that created today from but it seems my query is not excluding the data that created yesterday.

I already try expression this

```
['<', 'created', new Expression('NOW()')]
```

and this

```
$testQuery = self::find()->where([
    'and',
    ['=', 'status', self::STATUS_REJECTED],
    ['=', 'product_id', $this->product_id],
    ['=', 'email_address', $this->email_address],
    ['>', 'created', new Expression(date('m-d-Y H:i:s', $stamp))]
]);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($testQuery->all());
echo "</pre>";
```

And now I'm getting an SQL error

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '00:00:00)' at line 1 The SQL being executed was:
>   SELECT * FROM `product_offer` WHERE (`status` = 0) AND (`product_id` =
>   '111') AND (`email_address` = 'asrockg07@gmail.com') AND (`created` >
>   05-17-2018 00:00:00)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get count of items which are created today in yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083897/how-to-get-count-of-items-which-are-created-today-in-yii2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use raw SQL content with a `WHERE` call in string format, and it is also possible to and together two `WHERE` calls.  Putting this together, we can try the following:

```
$testQuery = self::find()->where([
    'and',
    ['=', 'status', self::STATUS_REJECTED],
    ['=', 'product_id', $this->product_id],
    ['=', 'email_address', $this->email_address]
])
->andWhere('created >= CURDATE()');
```

Note that I think you want to use `CURDATE` here, which corresponds to today at midnight, if you want to restrict to records created at any point today.

Comment: No need to add **and** in where automatically added by where function plus no need to use **=** instead use `'status' => self::STATUS_REJECTED,`

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect format for date. It should be `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $stamp)` for passed stamp or `date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $stamp)` to force midnight.

```
$testQuery = self::find()->where([
    'and',
    ['=', 'status', self::STATUS_REJECTED],
    ['=', 'product_id', $this->product_id],
    ['=', 'email_address', $this->email_address],
    ['>', 'created', date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $stamp)]
]);
```

---

Also you're using `yii\db\Expression` in a wrong way. You cannot pass value directly to `Expression`, this may open you to SQL Injection. You should use params if you need this.

```
$testQuery = self::find()->where([
    'and',
    ['=', 'status', self::STATUS_REJECTED],
    ['=', 'product_id', $this->product_id],
    ['=', 'email_address', $this->email_address],
    new Expression('created > :date', [':date' => date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $stamp)]),
]);
```